# Conditional probability moving marbles from one bag to another

Tags: combinatorics, conditional-probability

Suppose we have two bags of marbles, $C$ and $\bar C$. Marbles are red and green.

Initially, the bags are $C = \{ G, G, R, R, R, R \}$ and $\bar C = \{ G, R \}$. Then one marble is randomly moved from bag $C$ into bag $\bar C$.

Now you draw a marble from $\bar C$

First, what is the probability it's green?

Second, we've found out it is green. Knowing this, what's the probability that we moved a green marble from bag $C$ into bag $\bar C$ earlier?

This problem is different than other conditional probability problems (marble moves from one bag to another). Could someone walk me through this? I'm not sure how to deal with the changing variable.

Comment: What have you tried?  Just go case by case.  What is the probability that a green ball is selected from $C$?  Given that a green ball has been selected from $C$, what is the probability that a green ball is selected from $\bar C$?  Same for red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the probability of moving green from $C$ be $P(G_C)=1/3$, then
$P(R_C)=2/3$.

Probability of getting a green when $G_C$ has happened, $P(G_{\bar C}|G_C)=2/3$ and similarly $P(G_{\bar C}|R_C)=1/3$.
Since, $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$, so, $P(G_{\bar C}\cap G_C)=\frac23\frac13$ and $P(G_{\bar C}\cap R_C)=\frac13\frac23$

Using Bayes' Theorem,
$P(G_{\bar C})=\frac{P(G_{\bar C}\cap G_C)+P(G_{\bar C}\cap R_C)}{P(G_C)+P(R_C)}=\frac49$

---

Here, we have to find $P(G_{\bar C}|G_C)$.

Again using Bayes' Theorem:
$P(G_{\bar C}|G_C)=\frac{P(G_{\bar C}\cap G_C)}{P(G_{\bar C}\cap G_C)+P(G_{\bar C}\cap R_C)}=\frac{\frac29}{\frac49}=\frac12$

---

Just go with the flow. Even I was stumped a bit by the $2^{nd}$ part of the question, read it $3$ times and ... done!

Comment: This helped so much. I arrived at the same answer for part 1, but part 2 had me stuck!

Comment: @sar I'm glad I could be helpful :-)

Comment: Downvotes without comment aren't appreciated.

Comment: This is the correct answer, so not sure why it was downvoted.

Comment: @sar thank you for showing concern, but downvotes may have plenty of reasons and getting an incorrect answer is generally an unpopular one. It has to do with the post in general, how one has presented idea, formatting, way of explaining, etc. So, that's why when one downvotes it kind of "duty" to tell them about why they did so, so that the user may improve their post (and don't repeat it in future). But only downvoting doesn't really help anyone and when even I don't see any possible reason. Anyways, I left the comment so the downvoter may read in future or someone else provide a hint at it.